# How to mysql_query from same table with different where clause in same php file

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table containing 4 articles with id 1,2,3 and 4 as well as ordering value 1,2,3,4.
They have separate columns for their title, image etc. I need to get them distinctly with where clause. So i did:
For article 1:

```
//topstory1
$sql_topstory1 ="SELECT * FROM topstory WHERE story_active='1' && story_order='1'";
$result_topstory1  = mysql_query($sql_topstory1);
$row_topstory1     = mysql_fetch_array($result_topstory1);          
$story1_title      = $row_topstory1['story_title'];
$story1_abstract   = $row_topstory1['story_text'];
```

And for article 2

```
//topstory2
$sql_topstory2 ="SELECT * FROM topstory WHERE story_active='1' && story_order='2'";
$result_topstory2  = mysql_query($sql_topstory2);
$row_topstory2     = mysql_fetch_array($result_topstory2);          
$story2_title      = $row_topstory2['story_title'];
$story2_abstract   = $row_topstory2['story_text'];
```

As I have to reuse them in a page.

PROBLEM IS, the first query works but the second one doesn't. It seems like MySql cannot execute two consecutive queries on the same table in a single php file. But I think there is a simple solution to this...

Please help me soon :( Love you guys :)

Comment: are you sure you not trying to get article2 after closing the mysql connection? Please could you show us your database connection code

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible reasons for the second query to fail, but the fact that it's the second query in the file does not cause it to fail.

I would expect that article 2 does not have the active flag set to 1, causing you to get an empty result set.

Another option is that you may have closed the mysql connection after the first query, then you can't execute another query. (General rule: don't close database connections. PHP takes care of that.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just get them both with 1 query?

```
$sql_topstory ="SELECT * FROM topstory WHERE story_active='1' && story_order IN(1, 2) ORDER BY story_order DESC";

$result_topstory = mysql_query($sql_topstory) or trigger_error('Query Failed: ' . mysql_error());
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_topstory)) {
      $title[] = $row['story_title'];
      $abstract[] = $row['story_abstract'];
 }

 // Then to display

 echo 'Story 1 is ' . $title[0] . ' with an abstract of ' . $abstract[1];
```

There are plenty of ways to do this, this is just a simple demonstration.

Comment: This may solve the problem the OP has. But it does not correct the problematic code that caused it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = <<<SQL
   SELECT
      story_title
      , story_text
   FROM
      topstory
   WHERE
      story_active
   ORDER BY
      story_order ASC
SQL;

$result = mysql_query($query);

$stories = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $stories[] = $row;
}
```

Now you have an array of stories like so:

```
array(
   0 => array(
      'story_title' => ?
      , 'story_text' => ?
   )
   , 1 => array(
      'story_title' => ?
      , 'story_text' => ?
   )
)
```

Should be pretty easy to iterate through.